# RecatNative - Object keys are shown when logged ,but when displaying in app,it shows undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, javascript-objects

i want to display the keys of the object(*size*)..each *size* object have various keys ..so i tried to iterate keys using **Object.keys()**..but it didn't gave me the answer i thought,so help to rectify it .

Thanks In Advance ! :)

[image: this my firebase Realtime database]

when i run this code -
`{console.log(postDetail['sizes'])}`
it shows like these in prompt:
[image]

But when i try to display the keys in the App(the below code) -

```
{console.log(postDetail['sizes'])}
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
    {

        Object.keys(postDetail['sizes']).map((item) => {

            return <View>
                <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontWeight: 'normal', }}>{item}</Text>
            </View>
        })
    }
</View>
```

it show undefined like these
[image]

**help me to display object keys in the App !**

Comment: If you add `{console.log(postDetail['sizes'])}`to the line above `Object.keys(...)` what is the output

Comment: error: SyntaxError: E:\Android app\react native\Wardrobe\otherPages\PostDetailPage.js: Unexpected token, expected "}" (160:32)
  `158 |                             {
  159 |                                 console.log(postDetail['sizes'])
> 160 |                                 Object.keys(postDetail['sizes']).map((item) => {
      |                                 ^
  161 |                                     return <View >
  162 |                                 <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontWeight: 'normal', }}>{item}</Text>
  163 |                             </View>`

Comment: Please don't post long sections of code in comments - put the them in the question, properly formatted. Also, when responding to someone, notify them you responded by adding their name preceded by and at sign; like this @Jay

Comment: Sorry! @jay this is ,my 1st question on  _SO_  thanks for your rply i will rectify it !